# How to move and minimize Maui windows application programmatically

Tags: c#, maui, winui-3, .net-maui

I have a maui app with blazor and I'm creating a custom titlebar.

I about to close the maui app, using on blazor `Application.Current.Quit();`

Now how can i minimize and move maui app

My code blazor

```
private void MoveWindow()
{
    
}

private void MinimizeWindow()
{
        
}


private void CloseWindow() {
    Application.Current.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maui already has a function to minimize the application.

**Use the following in your blazor:**

```
private void MinimizeWindow()
{
#if WINDOWS
    var Window = App.Current.Windows.First();
    var nativeWindow = Window.Handler.PlatformView;
    IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);
    WindowId WindowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
    AppWindow appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(WindowId);

    var p = appWindow.Presenter as OverlappedPresenter;

    p.Minimize();
#endif
}
```

Comment: It works, is there any maui function to move window?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call native code for that.
Add a reference to `PInvoke.User32` package:

```
<PackageReference Include="PInvoke.User32" Version="0.7.104" Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))"/>
```

#### Minimize

As an example upon a button click we minimize the window:

```
void MinimizeWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
#if WINDOWS
            var mauiWindow = App.Current.Windows.First();
            var nativeWindow = mauiWindow.Handler.PlatformView;
            IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);

            PInvoke.User32.ShowWindow(windowHandle, PInvoke.User32.WindowShowStyle.SW_MINIMIZE);
#endif
}
```

#### Move

```
void MoveWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
#if WINDOWS
            var mauiWindow = App.Current.Windows.First();
            var nativeWindow = mauiWindow.Handler.PlatformView;
            IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);
            PInvoke.RECT rect;

            PInvoke.User32.GetWindowRect(windowHandle, out rect);
            (var width, var height) = GetWinSize(rect);

            PInvoke.User32.MoveWindow(windowHandle, 50, 0, width, height, true);

#endif
}

(int width, int height) GetWinSize(PInvoke.RECT rect) =>
            (rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
```

It's possible to resize the window with `MoveWindow()`, but since the aim in the question is to move the window only, then we supply the values of the current window's width and height as parameters.

Ps: Unfortunately I didn't find a simpler solution to get the window dimensions.

#### EDIT

A better alternative is to use [AppWindow.Move(PointInt32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.appwindow.move?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1):

```
#if WINDOWS
WindowId WindowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
AppWindow appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(WindowId);
appWindow.Move(new Windows.Graphics.PointInt32(x,y))
#endif
```

`x` and `y` are the coordinate for the desired new position. The origin (0,0) is the left upper corner of the screen.

For information about the screen dimensions:

- [Native api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.displayarea?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1): [Open app always in the center of the display - Windows 11 (WinUi 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71546846/5228202)
- [Maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/display): `var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;`

Comment: Maui does not have any function capable of doing this ?

And about the question of moving the window, can you tell me about it?

Comment: This mode using `appWindow.Move` looks interesting, how can I get x and y value from my app ?

Comment: depending where you want to move your window (the new position), i have included more details

Comment: What I try to do is the same as wpf  `DragMove()`